# Postgres foreign data wrapper between RDS databases

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have two Postgres databases in Amazon RDS that I'd like to be able to perform joins between. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/postgres-fdw.html) for creating a foreign table from one into the other. Everything seemed to work fine, but when I run a simple query like `select count(*) from table_in_other_db` I get:

```
ERROR:  could not connect to server "broad"
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out
```

Both of these databases are in the same security group and I can access them individually. I even tried adding the security group to its own inbound rules on port 5432. Can anyone think of why else this wouldn't work?

Comment: are they running in the same VPC? does the enpoint hostname resolve to public or private ip?

Comment: @BretzL same VPC, and they both have a public IP.

Comment: do you use the enpoint name like mypostgresql.c6c8dntfzzhgv0.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com or the ip (ip can change)? does it resolve to the private ip inside the vpc? See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=724964